# AWS cdk retrieve account number when working with roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, multi-factor-authentication, assume-role

I have the following `~/.aws/config` and try to run `ENV=dev cdk synth  --profile test --all`.

Inside CDK my code then tries to determine the profile's account number. Reading the environment variable `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT`. Sadly, this is returning `001xx`, and not `200xx`.

It seems it only detects the IAM user, and does not go down the rabbit hole using the assumed role. How can I retrieve the final role's target account number inside CDK?

```
[default]
region = eu-central-1

[profile test]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::200xx:role/RoleInTargetAccount
source_profile = dev_prof
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::001xx:mfa/lony
```

Comment: Did you mean to use the dev_prof profile, or the test profile, when invoking cdk?

Comment: As shown above, I use the dev_prof - this way it assumes the role.

Comment: Run: `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile test`. It will use the `dev_prof` credentials to assume the `arn:aws:iam::200xx:role/RoleInTargetAccount` role.

Comment: I need the ID inside CDK, but your point is right - I could add SDK code to make a lookup ... so no way to do this in CDK then? @jarmod did you already try this in CDK or did you just use the CLI command so far?

Comment: I'm just explaining how the ~/.aws/config file works for profiles that assumes roles.